# Python format date using only string format() method

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, format

What is the quick way to format date in python using only `.format` method?
I know there is a way to do it without using `strftime`. I need more elegant method.

Comment: There is an example in the Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-examples) under "Using type-specific formatting".

Answer (score 2):

I know a good method which is not widely known, but very useful.

Here is how you can do it:

```
from datetime import datetime
'{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M}'.format(datetime(2018, 12, 28, 10, 30))
```

The output is `2018-12-28 10:30`

Comment: I think this method is better almost every time. You don't need to import and call additional function `strftime` and it looks cleaner. Real life example: `return 
u'{0.start_date:%d.%m.%Y %H:%M} - {0.end_date:%d.%m.%Y %H:%M}: {0.number} moon day'.format(self)`