# Convert string "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" to timestamp in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help to convert this string '20190625091115' to timestamp '25-06-2019 09:11:15' in python. Format in 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS > Format out 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS'.

Comment: It's not a duplicate question! @m-r Have you fully read the explanation of my question? If so please explain me how this post could answer what I needed [Python format date using only string format() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953093/python-format-date-using-only-string-format-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First part would be creating datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "20190625091115"
format_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
After which format date is:

print(format_date)
2019-06-25 09:11:15

Little clarification here, on python reference page, you can see definition for '%Y%m%d%H%M%S') format specifiers I used.

%Y: Year with century as a decimal number, e.g. 1970, 1988, 2001, 2013
%m: Month as a zero-padded decimal number (e.g. 01, 02, ..., 12)
%d: Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number (e.g. 01, 02, ..., 31)
%H: Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number (e.g 00, 01, ..., 23)
%M: Minute as a zero-padded decimal number (e.g 00, 01, ..., 59)
%S: Second as a zero-padded decimal number (e.g. 00, 01, ..., 59)
%f: Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left (000000, 000001, ..., 999999)
%z: UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM, empty string if the the object is naive, (empty or +0000, -0400, +1030)
```